# Zoomed ImageView transition between activities

Tags: android

I'm trying to make shared ImageView between two activities (for example from activity A to activity B).
The problem is after this steps:

1. Image shared into activity
2. Image zoomed in activity B;
3. Going back from B activity to A;
4. Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giG0JLveZYk&feature=youtu.be) video

There is no problem without zooming: you can watch [this](https://youtu.be/D6e_KPrCJps)

My style-v21:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/explode</item>

    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@transition/change_image_transform</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@transition/change_image_transform</item>
</style>
```

My transition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

And my ImageActivity:

```
public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String IMAGE_URL = "image_url";
public static String TEXT = "text";
private ProgressBar spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoading);

    String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra(IMAGE_URL);
    String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(TEXT);

    if (text != null)
        tvName.setText(text);
    else tvName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
            .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, image, options, simpleImageLoadingListener);
}

SimpleImageLoadingListener simpleImageLoadingListener = new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
        String message = null;
        switch (failReason.getType()) {
            case IO_ERROR:
                message = "Input/Output error";
                break;
            case DECODING_ERROR:
                message = "Image can't be decoded";
                break;
            case NETWORK_DENIED:
                message = "Downloads are denied";
                break;
            case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                message = "Out Of Memory error";
                break;
            case UNKNOWN:
                message = "Unknown error";
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
}
```

My intent from activity A to activity B (ImageActivity)

```
   Intent goToImage = new Intent(InfoActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
        goToImage.putExtra(ImageActivity.IMAGE_URL, cafe.getImageUrl());
        goToImage.putExtra(ImageActivity.TEXT, cafe.getName());
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(InfoActivity.this,
                    imgCompany, "image");
            startActivity(goToImage, options.toBundle());
        } else {
            startActivity(goToImage);
        }
```

I know that happens because of different image size & scaletypes, on activity A it centerCrop and has fixed size, on activity B it maxtrix and match_parent.
How to make resize animation in transition?
In my case, resizing going after image being moved to it's position...

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: @gaurang no, I didn't..
I just call `image.resetZoom();` that resets images size to default in `onBackPressed()` and then call `super.onBackPressed();`